# Can a Mac act as Bluetooth receiver for sound?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, airplay

This is my setup to play music:

- Mac with iTunes
- 2 Airport Express' connected to two pair of active
  B&O speakers

I also have a turntable/record player that I want to use wirelessly with this setup. I therefore just ordered a [Bluetooth transmitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LB1628G). Now the question is if my Mac can receive A2DP (low latency AptX) from this device with its built in Bluetooth support or do I need to buy a separate receiver for the computer?

My plan is to use Rogue Amoeba's Line In app and redirect the sound from my turntable/Bluetooth combo to my Airport Express' but while waiting for my transmitter to arrive I have googled and it looks like a Mac can't act as a Bluetooth A2DP server. However, I also have a small portable Bluetooth speaker and that can act as a speaker phone and in Line In I can select this speaker both as output destination and input source, which seems to indicate that my Mac actually can receive sound from a Bluetooth source.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a solution using Airplay instead of Bluetooth, but I guess that is better anyway. The solutions is described in detail here

http://davidbo.livejournal.com/795.html

(page is added to Wayback Machine in case it disappears).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: "page is added to Wayback Machine in case it disappears". Do you understand what that sentence means?

Comment: Of course, but that doesn't resolve the issue. "Links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer. […] the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer." https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/222623

Comment: @grgarside That answer is a rule of thumb, not some kind of law of physics where an exception is either unthinkable or a sensation. FYI, the linked article is dynamic and will be updated when new information is available.